# Relay for Intermittent Wiper Function

Tags: relay, automotive, 12v, attiny85

I want to add an intermittent function to the wipers on my 40-year-old car without any additional switches.  The details of the wipers can be found here [http://www.globalsoftware-inc.com/coolerman/fj40/5G.htm].  The wiper knob closes the path to ground allowing the motor to begin sweeping the wipers.  (There is another ground at the motor that mechanically closes when the wipers are not parked.  This allows the wipers to park regardless of when the wipers are switched off.)  It seems that all I need to do is complete the path to ground whenever I want to sweep the wipers, but it seems too easy so I’m second guessing myself.  I’ve drawn out a small circuit using a ATtiny85 to detect if the wiper circuit is closed (not shown on the diagram).  If the circuit is closed (knob pulled out) for longer than one second, the wipers operate as long as the knob is out.  If the knob is pulled out and returned in less than one second, the uC activates the relay long enough to start a sweep and repeats this at a predetermined interval.

Am I missing something?  Is this a reasonable approach?  I chose an automotive relay I’ve used before, datasheet here [http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1809465.pdf] with a diode and RC snubber across the contacts.

[Edited from original to reflect accurate wiring.]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftxkp5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*To be completed by OP.*

```
                                 |   A   |   B   |   C   |
                                 +-------+-------+-------+
Everything off                   |12.9 V |12.9 V |12.9 V |
Bulb in, WIPER_LO closed         |   0 V |   0 V | 4.9 V |
Relay energised, WIPER_LO closed |   0 V |12.9 V | 4.9 V |
```

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fC4nIY.png)</sup>

[Second schematic illustrates switch and two ground paths.]

Comment: @Transistor why are you adding a schematic/answer in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Update: major rewrite after additional information.]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEReGZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Redraw of wiring based on [Toyota wiring mystery](http://www.globalsoftware-inc.com/coolerman/fj40/5G.htm).*

**Figure 1: how it works**

- In OFF position the RUN switch will keep the motor running at LO speed until it reaches the PARK position.
- In the OFF / PARK position the motor is shorted out. This causes dynamic braking of the wiper motor and will stop the motor abruptly preventing run-on into the RUN position.
- In LO speed the off contact is open, the LO is closed and the motor runs at low speed.
- In HI speed the other two contacts are open and the high-speed winding is energised.
- Note that + to GND short-circuits should never occur with this arrangement as the wiper switch contacts will be break before make.

**Figure 2: replacing switch with relays**

Figure 2 shows the rewiring for intermittent add-on control. I am recommending this approach rather than the single-relay approach of earlier edits as it provides complete isolation between the logic and the power wiring, gives you great flexibility in the logic and is simple to wire and understand.

There is one danger to be avoided in the circuit of Figure 2: when RLY2 is energised and high-speed is selected the LO wire must never connect to the PARK switch as it will toggle between + and GND while the HI winding is energised.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAO6y2.png)</sup>

*Figure 3. (Almost) full circuit.*

**Figure 3: the full circuit - how it works**

The original wiper knob has a few limitations: there are fixed internal links which cannot be broken. Disconnecting all the original wires - except the GND wire - allows us to monitor both LO and HI settings using the logic circuit without interference from the +12 V supply.

- R1 and 2 pull up the /LO (not LO) and /HI (not HI) lines when not selected.
- Selecting LO or HI will pull the corresponding line low. Both lines high indicates OFF position selected.
- The ATiny executes the logic for the relays.
- Q1 and 2 are open-collector drivers for RLY1 and RLY2. D1 and D2 provide inductive kick-back protection for Q1 and Q2 when switched off.
- As required in the Figure 2 comment above we need to ensure that if RLY2 is energised then RLY1 is too. This should be done in software but D3 ensures that if Q2 (and RLY2) is switched on then RLY1 will be energised regardless of the quality of the software. ;^)

**Software**

As Dwayne Reid points out in his answer there are some neat tricks you can do with this to use an on-off-on sequence to set and modify the delay time. This was in my mind as I wrote my original because I remember reading an [Elektor](http://elektor.com) article (April 1980) on the subject. Simple micros such as the ATiny weren't available then and the design used some tricky logic to make the timer 'memory'. The Elektor design is referenced in [US patent 4388574](http://www.google.com/patents/US4388574).

Comment: I didn't realize you could add from CircuitLab directly. Thanks.  I added the 12V detect circuit to the question. Is there an advantage of the D1/C2/R3/R4 circuit over a BJT?

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: I understand the NPN and 10k pull-up.  Unsure of the rest, but let me try.  The base of Q2 is connected to the "always on" 12V supply and when the wiper switch is open, the NPN is on and the U1 input is LOW.  When the wiper switch is closed, the NPN is on and the U1 input is high.  The advantage is that the uC would know when the knob is pushed in but the wipers haven't yet parked?

Comment: I think you've got it, provided that it's a typo in your third sentence, "_When the wiper switch is closed, the NPN is **on**"_ should read **off**. Everything else is fine. Is that any advantage to you? What make / model of car is it as a matter of interest?

Comment: Yes, a typo.  It is an advantage and it's for a '74 Toyota Land Cruiser (FJ40).  Quite annoying to pull out a knob (not near the steering wheel) and push it back in every time you want a single sweep.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: I replaced the png with a circuit in the original post and modified it to show the three connections I have available; +12V, wiper, and GND.  I believe it is the same except I cannot add D1.  I can only modify the circuit inside the box.

Comment: We're getting there. (1) Don't forget you have the park contact in parallel with the knob. (2) Since you can't put in my D1, your D4 and D3 aren't needed. (3) With your re-sketch it's now obvious that we have no input protection against an inductive kick from the motor on turn-off or brush sparking. I'll copy the schematic with a suggestion for a mod.

Comment: I don't understand the separate grounds.  If both wires are bolted to the chassis (ground) aren't they really the same ground but connected further from the uC?  Could I address it differently on the board?

Comment: On your schematic you show the high-current of the motor return passing through the circuit board common out to ground. Any resistance along this track will cause voltage increase and noise on the micro-controller negative and could cause problems. If you can only manage one ground then put it on the relay contact and tee the electronics ground off it rather than the other way around.

Comment: Ok I understand. On the PCB I have the wiper pad very close to the relay common and the ground pad very close to the NO contact. The high-current path is as short as possible (and over 200 mil wide).  Thanks again.

Comment: To avoid completing the circuit with a second ground, (and accurately reflect the actual wiring) I revised the circuit at the top of the page using the relay to create intermittent sweeps by opening the relay for the delay.  However, Q2 doesn't operate as I expected and the bulb I have substituted for the motor always illuminates to some degree.

Comment: Welcome back! (1) What wattage bulb? (2) "_by opening the relay for the delay_". By this you mean energising the relay for the delay (which would be correct)? (3) I've added labels A, B & C to your circuit and a table of expected values. Please edit to with actual readings. (4) What is actually setting the delay? A pot on the ATtiny?

Comment: I measured just what you predicted I would.  Speaking of bulbs, I think a dim one might be slowly illuminating in my head about now.  I do not have a bulb in place of the motor, I have an LED and 680Ω resistor in series!  My apologies. I measure ~3mA at the LED which is enough to illuminate it and I assumed the motor would be energized.  The 3mA is the current that is flowing from the base to the emitter of Q2?  Incidentally, I added R7 to create a voltage divider for the base of Q2 but now I'm not sure that was necessary either.

Comment: I had a hunch that it might be an LED. Try it with a 6 W tail lamp or similar to be a bit more realistic. You might want to add in a switch to simulate the 'park' switch function too. The base of a transistor is current controlled and the 3k3 resistor will limit it to \$\frac {12V}{3k3} = 4~mA\$ which will be fine. Keep going!

Comment: The initial schematic I posted did not accurately illustrate the switch and I posted a revised one.  The wiper knob switches the 12V from the motor between two ground paths; one is a permanent ground for continuous operation, and the other has a switch that is opened by a cam when the wipers complete a sweep.  When the relay is energized, the wipers complete the sweep and park.  The delay lasts until the relay is de-energized momentarily.  My question now is if D4 and/or D5 are necessary, good practice, unnecessary, or not a good idea (or none of the above).

Comment: @unix: Sorry for the delay. I've done a complete re-write having spent some more time analysing the Toyota diagrams and the additional information you provided. (We had completely missed the fact that the motor is deliberately shorted out when park position is reached.) The new design is much cleaner and has complete separation between the motor wiring and the logic. I think you will find it much more simple to program and wire.

Comment: Just when I started to think I knew what I was doing... The logic part I understand.  However, I don't quite understand the connections of the relays.  Perhaps you can map them in the circuit I provided above.  I also couldn't figure out a way to cleverly diagram the mechanical push/pull knob but hopefully it makes sense.  Was my last circuit an unwise design?  Will this two-relay design allow the wipers to operate if the uC fails?  Thanks.

Comment: Your diagram of the knob is fine and I've updated mine to use your layout. The problem with our original work and your design is that we missed the motor short-circuit in the park position and this would cause problems. Most intermittent wiper switches have additional contacts for the intermittent. Yours doesn't and I can't see any way of mixing the logic and relays while making it short circuit proof. For intermittent use you're going to have to "train" the micro with an on-off-on sequence so, unfortunately, you can't use the same switch should the micro fail. Read my post a few times ...

Comment: I truly appreciate your patience.  I think I understand. The mechanical knob is only communicating with the uC, which controls the relays.  (I won't admit how many times I read your post.)  As you already stated, only the ground wire is connected to run the wipers.  Controlling the delay can be done as @Dwayne mentioned or several other methods.

Comment: Do you see any reason that I couldn't use internal pull-ups for the HI and LO uC inputs?

Comment: I'm glad you got it. Don't worry about how long it took to get it. It took me quite a while to figure out what was going on. Internal pull-ups are fine.

Comment: I put the circuit together on the breadboard and changed the code to let the user set the interval using the time between knob pulls.  It worked, of course.  Put together wiring harness connectors and it worked perfectly in the truck as well!  Looking forward to getting the PCBs and putting one together.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'll think of you smiling every time you pull the knob!

Comment: I assembled a prototype and the system works fine.  I added some protection into the circuit but am uncertain about the fuse for the vr/uC. I posted a write-up [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/250687/24v-circuit-protection-fuse-tvs-diode-rc-snubber) but received no responses.  Would really appreciate you taking a look if you have a few minutes some time.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answers, you may want to consider a technique that I used maybe 20 years ago: the wiper control determines the delay time.  No extra switches are needed.

What happens is that you activate the wiper control momentarily, then turn the control OFF.  The wipers continue their sweep and come back home - but now the circuit is Armed.  When the desired time between sweeps has elapsed, activate the wiper again and turn the control off.  The micro measures the time between those two activations and continues to repeat that interval forever.

To turn the interval timer OFF, turn the wiper control ON for more than 1 full sweep.  The microcontroller detects that the switch is closed for more than the original time and goes back to the idle state.

Couple of other things: I time the duration of the initial ON pulse and replicate that pulse width on the relay.  I also start a timer when the system is in the Armed state and force the system back to idle mode if too much time has passed before the 2nd sweep is registered.   This helps eliminate unintended wiper sweeps if someone who is not familiar with the system cycles the wipers only once.

Comment: That's a novel idea.  It presently uses momentary contact of the washer switch to cycle through delay periods (which works fine since it takes a while before you'd ever spray the windshield).  I've seen another that uses the OFF and HI positions to travel up and down a "delay ladder."  I like your method and it would only be a change to the code.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @DwayneReid: Was the wiper circuit your own or was it, by any chance, the Elektor circuit of April 1980? See the update to my answer.